# Node.js static translations

Tags: node.js, internationalization

In a Node.js/Express application I have a file like this one

```
const sharedLocals = {
    BTN_CLOSE: 'close',
    BTN_CANCEL: 'cancel',
    BTN_SAVE: 'save',
    BTN_CONFIRM: 'Ok'
};

export default sharedLocals;
```

Later I use them to display alerts and other messages.
This is how I initiate the server and i18n for translation.

```
import i18n from 'i18n';
import express from 'express';
import dashboard from './routes/dashboard';

const server = express();

i18n.configure({
  locales:['en', 'se'],
  directory: __dirname + '/i18n',
  defaultLocale: 'se'
});

server.use(i18n.init);

server.use('/', dashboard);

server.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send(err ? err : 'Something went wrong');
    i18n.init(req, res);
    res.local('__', res.__);
})

server.listen(config.port, () => {  
  console.info(chalk.green('Server listening on port', config.port));
  console.log(i18n.__('cancel'));
});
```

I want to translate the from **sharedLocals.js**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: flagged with i18next...but seems not related to i18next - should know it our syntax is different: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware

Comment: I doesn't help me. I do not know how to call i18n in other js files.